# Easy merging in svn using git-svn

Tags: svn, git, merge, git-svn

At work we are using a lot of branches in SVN and there are problems in merging. I heard that a good idea is to use git better merging with git-svn. I try to play with it using msysgit, however its not as easy as it seems.

I know I can checkout the whole project using `git svn clone -s`, however it does not see branches(as normal git branches). I find git-svn very hard to use compare to git or svn.

Could you describe in steps how to do that kind of merging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

git-svn will gives you a branches for each branches and tag in SVN (unless you use a [ruby script like svn2git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572893/cloning-a-non-standard-svn-repository-with-git-svn/572898#572898))

The idea is to always `git-svn rebase`  / `git-svn dcommit` a SVN branch.
ie, you will synchronize a Git branch with a SVN one (`git-svn rebase`), and you will update an SVN branch from the new commits in the corresponding Git branch (`git-svn dcommit`).

Any local Git branches, with all their fancy merges, must be *local* (i.e. all those branches/merges in Git won't have any equivalent in the SVN repo)

As the caveat in the `git-svn` goes (see the SO question "[git-svn merge 2 svn branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693771/git-svn-merge-2-svn-branches)"):

> For the sake of simplicity and interoperating with a less-capable system (SVN), it is recommended that all `git svn` users `clone`, `fetch` and `dcommit` directly from the SVN server, and avoid all git `clone`/`pull`/`merge`/`push` operations between git repositories and branches.
>   The recommended method of exchanging code between git branches and users is `git format-patch` and `git am`, or just '`dcommit`'ing to the SVN repository.
>
> Running `git merge` or `git pull` is NOT recommended on a branch you plan to `dcommit` from.
>   Subversion does not represent merges in any reasonable or useful fashion; so users using Subversion cannot see any merges you've made. Furthermore, if you merge or pull from a git branch that is a mirror of an SVN branch, `dcommit` may commit to the wrong branch.