# Create a master git repository for multiple git-svn repositories

Tags: git, svn, repository, git-svn

I have a project which consists of several services, 
each in their own SVN repository and a build script that checks out each SVN repository as a folder in a single `/project` directory along with a `/project` level `Makefile` to recursively build the whole project.

Visually it looks something like this:

```
/project
  Makefile
  /service1    # First service (SVN repository)
    /.svn
  /service2    # Second service (SVN repository)
    /.svn
  ...
```

**I am trying to convert the project into a *single* shareable git repository to collaborate with teammates on without removing the ability to commit back to the original SVN repositories.**

My current idea is to check out each SVN repository (`/service1`, `/service2`, etc.) using git-svn and then create a master git repository at the `/project` level to group them into a single repository. The hypothesized project structure would look something like this:

```
/project
  /.git      # Master git repository
  Makefile
  /service1    # First service (SVN repository)
    /.git      # .git directory for git-svn checkout of service 1
  /service2    # Second service (SVN repository)
    /.git      # .git directory for git-svn checkout of service 2
  ...
```

**Will this work? Is there a simpler solution?**

Note: I *do not* have the authority to redefine the project structure or the structure of the SVN repositories.

Comment: There are no .svn folders for a git-svn checkout. Do you need them side by side with .git folders for some reason?

Comment: @prusswan Nope. I haven't used git-svn much so I didn't realize that it doesn't create the .svn folders. I'll update the question to reflect your observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can work, provided you consider `/project` as a parent repository referencing the `servicexx` git repos as [submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html).

That way, other collaborators can reference only the parent repo, and get back all the submodules in it.
As explained in "[True Nature of submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194)", they can then create/checkout branches within those submodules and start modifying them.

Make sure though than one branch is dedicate for `git svn dcommit` (merge back to SVN):
See "[Overcome git svn caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634099/overcome-git-svn-caveats/5634215#5634215)" and "[Easy merging in svn using git-svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322105/easy-merging-in-svn-using-git-svn/3322302#3322302)".