# Working with SVN branches git-style

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I've been working for a couple of years with git and I have become used to constant branching.  Each 1-2 day long task usually has its own branch and, of course, if there are preempting tasks, they are developed in separate branches as well. Now I'm joining a project that is managed in SVN with almost no branching. I'm wondering whether there is anything that prevents me from branching in SVN similarly to how I work in git (I cannot use git because of local policies). I mean, is there a technical reason that makes it impractical to create and merge branches all the time in SVN?

Comment: No, not really. The main difference is that SVN branches are stored in the central SVN repository, and are thus visible by all your co-workers. These are called feature branches in SVN. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html

Comment: How can they tell if you use a git-svn clone locally?

Comment: YES there is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692950/whats-the-difference-between-svn-and-git-for-merging, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471606/how-and-or-why-is-merging-in-git-better-than-in-svn/2472251#2472251, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475831/merging-hg-git-vs-svn/2477089#2477089

Comment: And git-svn is a possible solution, but beware of the caveats: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322105/easy-merging-in-svn-using-git-svn/3322302#3322302

Comment: @JBNizet Have you tried to manage and use the merge features of SVN? I understand FireAphis's concerns. I'd use git-svn myself.

Comment: @CarlNorum, I guess they cannot, but it's a new place and I prefer to check other options before I start with renegade activities on my first day :)

Comment: I've used SVN for years, and used maintenance and feature branches very often, yes. Sure, git is better at merging. That doesn't make feature branches impossible to use in SVN.

Comment: @FireAphis, that sounds reasonable, but don't forget that you can be a force for good!