# Can I remove git-svn metadata from specific commits?

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm working in a git-svn cloned repository.  I've got a git branch tracking a Subversino feature branch, which I've made a load of commits to, and have `dcommit`ed them to Subversion.  Merging that Subversion branch is proving to be really painful, so I'd like to just rebase that branch onto master (or cherry-pick the commits I care about), and get rid of the Subversion branch.  (I don't mind losing the Subversion merge history).

If I hadn't pushed the commits to Subversion it would be fine, but if I rebase/cherry-pick the commits to master, they come complete with the `git-svn-id` which I presume will cause the `dcommit` process to explode spectacularly (although I'm too afraid to try it).

Is there a way to strip out the `git-svn-id` (and any other less-obvious metadata that might cause problems) for those commits that I want to bring across?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry no straight forward answer for this one. See these questions:

[Using git-svn (or similar) *just* to help out with an svn merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945842/using-git-svn-or-similar-just-to-help-out-with-an-svn-merge)

[git-svn merge 2 svn branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693771/git-svn-merge-2-svn-branches)

Comment: I hadn't seen these answers, they're kinda encouraging though, thanks!