# Merge branch that was created with the same name as deleted one

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-svn

We use  Subversion as primary VCS. And I use Git as convenient client.
And now I failed  to merge feature branch into release branch correctly.

Originally  feature branch (**feature**) was created from release branch (**Release1.0**).
Later it was realized that **Release1.0** was closed and now  the feature should be developed based on **Release2.0**.
No problem.

```
git rebase --onto Release2.0 HEAD~30
```

Some commit to match code evolution in Release2.0 branch

```
git rebase -i HEAD~14
```

At this point I decided not to dcommit changes into svn, but keep all development history in feature branch and do merge with release branch  (since later I will probably cherrypick this into another place)

```
svn rm ....feature
svn cp ....Release2.0 ...feature -m"Feature based on Release2.0"
git svn fetch && git svn rebase
git branch tmp Release2.0 && git checkout tmp
git rebase --onto feature HEAD~35
git checkout feature && git merge tmp
git svn dcommit
```

To keep svn:mergeinfo in sync I  did the actual merge in svn

```
svn merge -rxxx:yyy feature
git-svn  fetch && git svn rebase
```

Done?  No! The feature branch and Release2.0 branch was not merged  according to Git.  The Release branch just got one additional commit.

**The problem is:**  though the feature branch was deleted and that re-created from another place, the Git shows merge at this point.  Thus  it  refuse to show  merge operation (there are commits that was not merged, but they are from deleted part of branch)  So i should use another name when creating feature branches in such cases to avoid such problems.

Well, I’ve got the lesson  and now I know how to avoid this in future,  but is it possible to fix this right now or is it possible  to workaround  this in other way in future?
I've tried to change manually svn:mergeinfo it works but this means  I need mark all commits till branching point as merged in svn:mergeinfo.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to confirm the limitations of **[`git-svn`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn)** regarding rebase, as presentated in its [CAVEATS section](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#_caveats):

> For the sake of simplicity and interoperating with Subversion, it is recommended that all `git svn` users `clone`, `fetch` and `dcommit` directly from the SVN server, and avoid all `git clone/pull/merge/push` operations between git repositories and branches.

You can recreate the merge information on SVN side, but Git would not reflect the merge after `git-svn  fetch` && `git svn rebase`.
By default, `git-svn` doesn't care about merginfo.

However, "[Can git-svn correctly populate svn:mergeinfo properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5983620/6309)" mentions

> the current state of affairs with `git-svn` has changed since it was asked.
>   Specifically, in git 1.7.5, there is some limited support for setting the `svn:mergeinfo` when `dcommitting` back to svn.
>
> `git svn dcommit` now accepts the `-mergeinfo=<mergeinfo>` flag.